# log4j2 writing method and class

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, pattern-layout

I'm using log4j2 in a java program..
this is the line of code where it is initialized

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("application-
log");
```

and this is the configuration file where the format is decided

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorinterval="30" status="info" strict="true">
<Properties>
    <Property name="logApplicativo">../logs/logApplicativo.log</Property>
    <Property name="logCdr">../logs/logCdr.log</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m MDC%X%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile   name="fileLogApplicativo" 
    fileName="${logApplicativo}" filePattern="${log-Applicativo}-%d{yyyy-MM-
    dd}-%i.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true" 
    ignoreExceptions="false" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d [%-6p] %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile >
    <RollingRandomAccessFile  name="fileLogCdr" fileName="${logCdr}" 
    filePattern="${log-Cdr}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d %-5p %c{2} - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <AsyncRoot level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </AsyncRoot>
    <AsyncLogger name="application-log" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="fileLogApplicativo" level="debug"/>>
    </AsyncLogger>
    <AsyncLogger name="cdr-log" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogCdr" level="debug"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
</Loggers>
```

I do not understand why, but class name, code name, line code arent printed. Probably the problem is trivial but I'm going crazy from one day.

Thank you all

Comment: Show us what is the actual output.

Comment: 2017-10-26 11:46:23,740 [DEBUG ] ?.(:) - START APPLICAZIONE CDR-
2017-10-26 11:46:24,181 [DEBUG ] ?.(:) - caricamento del file config.xml
2017-10-26 11:46:24,181 [INFO  ] ?.(:) - recupero sul db i dati
2017-10-26 11:46:25,197 [INFO  ] ?.(:) - non ci sono dati da inserire

Comment: Also please share how you configure logger in your log4j2.xml. Please update your question with  the configuration. Do not post it in comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using asynchronous loggers or asynchronous appenders try adding `includeLocation="true"` to your logger or appender configuration.

You can read more about it in the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation)